# Cannot select option tag which is disabled

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have a problem with my select tag. When I use x-editable:

```
<a href="#" editable-select="myId" e-ng-options="m.id as m.name disable when m.deleted for m in data">...</a>
```

So, My select tag cannot select the disabled option when I perform it. But, when i don't set disabled in 'e-ng-option', it works. Here my picture. As you can see, the 'Enquiry 10 %' option tag is not selected even though I passed the model (myId):

[image]

Please take a look and help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: i guess myId is a boolean variable defined ?, if so , editable-select would be false only if myId is false

Comment: @AgbalayaRasaq Thank you. But, I passed exactly the myId on both type and value

Comment: Its a bit confusing , If you marked something disable , you cant select it anymore and that the proper feature.

Can you elaborate what you want exactly? Or create some plank.

Comment: @Viplock Thank you. However, when I use ng-repeat in option tag of select tag, I still can select the disabled option. Now, my situation is e-ng-options, not ng-repeat.